# Code efficiency for drawing in C#?

Tags: c#, compact-framework

Just to know the best practice or code efficiency, I am having this piece of code :

Just to note: I am using .Net Compact Framework.

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (BmpScreen == null)
    {
      BmpScreen = new Bitmap(ClientRectangle.Width, ClientRectangle.Height);
    }

    using (Graphics gBmpScreen = Graphics.FromImage(BmpScreen))
    {
         // some drawing using gBmpScreen
    }
    // finally
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(BmpScreen, 0, 0);
}
```

In this piece of code in the `Paint` method I am creating a `Graphics`  object every time,

my question is it better to do it like this or is it better to create the graphics object only once in the beginning ?

Comment: `PaintEventArgs` already gives you a `Graphics` object via [the Graphics property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.painteventargs.graphics.aspx). Why can't you use the one that's already been created and handed to you?

Comment: The answer ought to be fairly obvious, drawing the same bitmap over and over again is not usually efficient.  If you don't draw the same thing repeatedly then you shouldn't be using a bitmap but use the DoubleBuffered property and draw to e.Graphics.

Comment: I am using .Net Compact Framework...

Comment: @Praveen As far as I can tell, the NETCF supports the `Graphics` property on `PaintEventArgs`. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.painteventargs_members(v=vs.71).aspx) indicates that it is "Supported by the .NET Compact Framework".

Comment: Recommended practice is to test and measure. Does this above give you acceptable performance? Yes? It's good. If not, consider other ideas and gather metrics to see which is more acceptable.

Comment: @Praveen - Yes.  You should only create a single Bitmap reference, otherwise your other instances will have to be collected, which is a waste of resources until the time they are collected by the garbage collector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure of the performance difference, but I'd recommend allocating and disposing of your back buffer Bitmap and Graphics objects in OnResize.  I've found for most custom controls you can separate the actual work of updating the back buffer as close as possible to where the data changes occur, and simplify the the OnPaint to only blit the back buffer bitmap to the system's Graphics.  This worked well for a custom graph control I wrote, since the data did not change in response to user interaction.  It was contained in a gesture scrolling control and greatly improved scrolling animation.  But you could probably extend the pattern to handle more interactive controls by calling Update() in response to user interaction changes to force the OnPaint in the scope of your handler.

Comment: The reason I recommended allocating and disposing your back buffer Bitmap and Graphics in OnResize is because as your control is resized you'll need different sized back buffer objects.  You'll pay some performance hit from allocating your Graphics object on each OnPaint, but you might simply test and compare the performance difference by allocating your Graphics once at object at the same time as your Bitmap.  You'll probably see more performance by moving drawing code out of OnPaint and closer to where you handle model changes as opposed to changes from back buffer allocation.